# Error can't create a new Web3 object on angular

Tags: web3js, nodejs, angular2

I've tried on ubuntu, windows with different versions and browsers. web3 1 latest beta:

> WARNING in ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/api.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'vm' in
>   'C:\Users\x\Desktop\backmeapp\node_modules\asn1.js\lib\asn1'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   'C:\Users\x\Desktop\backmeapp\node_modules\eth-lib\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   'C:\Users\x\Desktop\backmeapp\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/src/index.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   'C:\Users\x\Desktop\backmeapp\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\src'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in
>   'C:\Users\x\Desktop\backmeapp\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'https' in
>   'C:\Users\x\Desktop\backmeapp\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'os' in
>   'C:\Users\x\Desktop\backmeapp\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/browserify-sign/browser/index.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
>   'C:\Users\x\Desktop\backmeapp\node_modules\browserify-sign\browser'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'stream' in
>   'C:\Users\x\Desktop\backmeapp\node_modules\cipher-base' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/hash-base/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'stream' in
>   'C:\Users\x\Desktop\backmeapp\node_modules\hash-base'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough the proper answer to your issue might probbably be to install the module you have referenced, I would strongly recommend you to use the [truffle angular boilerplate](https://truffleframework.com/boxes) instead.

It will save you ages worth of nerves, believe me.

**EDIT:** 
After thoroughly reading your errors again, I see that it requires "crypto", which is a default package now, breaking old dependencies. Here is a [patch](https://gist.github.com/niespodd/1fa82da6f8c901d1c33d2fcbb762947d).

Comment: It seems like there are missing file even inside the web3 packages. All I can see on the official documentation is "npm install web3" so I thought it was a self-contained package.

Comment: you should try which version of web3 you require. `npm install web3@0` will get you the latest release of web3 0.x.x .

Comment: yes I did want the last one, but as you said there were many missing modules that I have no idea how to set up correctly

Comment: see the edit on my answer.

Comment: jeez dude answer of links with one dead so 1/2 of your answer is correct